# Possible to have AWS Spot instances launch and run only when 'price is right', and if not then run on standard instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a web application running on a single small instance. Most of the time this is fine. However, occassionally our application does intensive queries and utilizes more CPU than the small instance can handle.

What I am wondering is; is there a way to have a SPOT instance (C1 High CPU Medium) launch and run while the spot price is low? Ie, have it run always as the 'main server' unless the spot price goes up; and then just revert (seamlessly) back to our reserved small instance - for the rare times the spot price increases?

Basically - a way to get a high cpu instance on the cheap...and our small instance will suffice 'Most of the time' anyway, so a failsafe to it is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take look at [AWS Spot Labs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-labs/). You can get access to some advanced features that will allow you to

> explore new ways to optimize your Amazon EC2 costs...

In the meanwhile, you can use your reserved or on-demand instances in an [auto-scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) group. Then while your Spot server is running, the load should be minimal and you will have a minimal number of on-demand instances. Once the spot instance is going down, you will start scaling up the on-demand (or reserved) instances to compensate for the lack of the main machine.

Actually you can even have your Spot Instances in a different (lower threshold) auto scaling group and launch several cheaper spot instances when they are available. See more details in: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US-SpotInstances.html